# EJB module - files

Tags: ejb, message, message-driven-bean

Can anyone explain me what are ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi , ejb-jar.xml ,ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi and ibm_ejbext.properties. What are these files and what is configured in these files. What is the need of all these files in ejb project.

What does ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi do and how it should be configured for message driven bean? Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

- ejb-jar.xml is the standard EJB deployment descriptor.  It is where you declare which EJBs exist in your module.
- ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi is a file specific to WebSphere Application Server that contains binding information (where in JNDI should the EJB be bound, and where in JNDI should the EJB find the resources it uses).  The ".xmi" file format is specific to EJB 2.1 and lower modules and has been replaced by the [ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) in EJB 3.0 and higher modules.  The ".xmi" file format is in the [XMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) file format as generated by [EMF](https://eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) and is barely documented (there is some basic information in the WAS_HOME/web directory of an installation, but you have to have some familiar with EMF to use it).  Typically, the file is edited using RAD or modified during application deployment.
- ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi is another file specific to WebSphere Application Server that contains various extensions to the specific (e.g., eager EJB initialization, stateful session timeouts, etc.).  It is also only used for EJB 2.1 modules and lower and has been replaced by ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml.
- ibm_ejbext.properties is another file specific to WebSphere Application Server that is generated by EJB deploy and is not intended to be used by developers.

To manually configure ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi, it's easiest to deploy the application, specify binding information, and then look at the result in `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cell/applications/APP.ear/deployments/APP/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi`.